# Permissions on dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

I have 2 sets of data that must be used from 2 different groups of user, let me say:

- Dataset A and Dataset B from Group 1
- Dataset C, Dataset D and Dataset E from Group 2

Within each group, I need to have some users who chan only see dashboard (do not modifiy, do not create new chart/dashboard, do not promote/publish dashboard) and some others who can create their own dashboards, but do not publish them.

How can I do?

I try to create a gamma user with access on dataset permission and only read permission on dashboard, but it does not work.

Have I to create new rules by code? In this case, how can I do

Answer (score 0):

Create the following roles:-

1. Role with view access for Datasets A and  B
2. Role with  create access for Datasets A and B
3. Role with view access for Datasets C, D  and E
4. Role with  create access for Datasets C, D and E

Then assign a user the Gamma role and the corresponding new role created above. It is  not recommendable to alter the 3 base roles(Admin, Alpha and Gamma)

Comment: Thanks @Lenin
I'll try to do what you explain, but user with dataset + only_view + Gamma role can create a his own dashboard anyway.
I suppose Gamma user has too many permissions.
So I wonder which is the minimum set of permission I can assign to an user.
Is there a detailed explanation for each possible permission?
Thank you very much anyway